# Can a .net C# windows application be run on Adobe Air

Tags: c#, windows, air, adobe

I have to make an application that can be run on both windows and Mac. I have to make it in C#.Can a .net C# windows application be run on Adobe Air so that it can be run on any environment?

Comment: It's time to make your mind up whether you want to code for Air or C#

Comment: Use MonoMac, it's fairly complete.

Comment: "Can a .net C# windows application be run on Adobe Air so that it can be run on any environment?" **- No**

Answer (score 5):

Try to built your c# application on [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Mono is a software platform designed to allow developers to easily create cross platform applications. Sponsored by Xamarin, Mono is an open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework based on the ECMA standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime. A growing family of solutions and an active and enthusiastic contributing community is helping position Mono to become the leading choice for development of Linux applications.